# REDIPS get results as array from function and pass it to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drag-and-drop

Im using REDIPS library so i can drag and drop some elements in a table. Following the provided examples by the library, I want to get the save_content() result as an array so I can insert those values inside my DB. This is my approach, but it doesn't work. Right now I get the value in an input displayed as text

```
            save_content = function (tbl) {
                    var query = '',     // define query parameter
                    tbl_start,      // table loop starts from tbl_start parameter
                    tbl_end,        // table loop ends on tbl_end parameter
                    tbl_rows,       // number of table rows
                    cells,          // number of cells in the current row
                    tbl_cell,       // reference to the table cell
                    t, r, c, d;     // variables used in for loops
                    // first sort tables array to it's original order
                    tables.sort(function (a, b) {
                        return a.idx - b.idx;
                    });
                    // if input parameter is undefined, then method will return content from all tables
                    if (tbl === undefined) {
                        tbl_start = 0;
                        tbl_end = tables.length - 1;
                    }
                    // if input parameter is out of range then method will return content from first table
                    else if (tbl < 0 || tbl > tables.length - 1) {
                        tbl_start = tbl_end = 0;
                    }
                    // else return content from specified table
                    else {
                        tbl_start = tbl_end = tbl;
                    }
                    // iterate through tables
                    for (t = tbl_start; t <= tbl_end; t++) {
                        // define number of table rows
                        tbl_rows = tables[t].rows.length;
                        // iterate through each table row
                        for (r = 0; r < tbl_rows; r++) {
                            // set the number of cells in the current row
                            cells = tables[t].rows[r].cells.length;
                            // iterate through each table cell
                            for (c = 0; c < cells; c++) {
                                // set reference to the table cell
                                tbl_cell = tables[t].rows[r].cells[c];
                                // if cells isn't empty (no matter is it allowed or denied table cell)
                                if (tbl_cell.childNodes.length > 0) {
                                    // cell can contain many DIV elements
                                    for (d = 0; d < tbl_cell.childNodes.length; d++) {
                                        // childNodes should be DIVs, not \n childs
                                        if (tbl_cell.childNodes[d].tagName === 'DIV') { // and yes, it should be uppercase
                                            var value = $(tbl_cell).find("input").val();

                                            query += 'p[]=' + tbl_cell.childNodes[d].id //obj id
                                            + '_' + value + '_' + r + '_' + c + '&';
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // cut last '&'
                    query = query.substring(0, query.length - 1);
                    // return prepared parameters (if tables are empty, returned value could be empty too)
                    return query;
                };
```

I would like to get the query value as an array so i can insert the values into the database without using $_REQUEST

```
  function save() {
$('#moverCita').modal('toggle');
var content = REDIPS.drag.save_content();
document.getElementById("moverCitaRow").value = content;
```

}

I get the value as text inside the input

update.php

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
 if(isset($_POST['moverCitaRow'])){
  if (!empty($_POST['moverCitaRow'])) {

  $content = $_POST['moverCitaRow'];

  $content = @$_REQUEST['p'];

  if(is_array($content)) {
    foreach ($content as $c) {
      list($job_id, $job_bay_id, $row, $col) = explode('_', $c);

      try {
        update_calendar($job_id, $job_bay_id, $row, $col);

      } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = $ex->getMessage();
        $_SESSION["errorType"] = "danger";
      }
    }
  }

}

else {
  echo '<center><strong style="color:red;">Llenar todos los campos 
    requeridos</strong></center><br>';
}
```

}
}